# How do I go about creating an ssh or any linux terminal view for my android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, terminal

So I am trying to create my own ssh terminal with android studio. I got the connection and basic commands 
 to work using jsch but the problem is that I have to hard code it or if not then implement a text box with a button kind of thing.

What I'm trying to get at is I want my view to look like a linux terminal instead of a button and textview but I can't seem to find any information on how to go about doing it. So wanted to know if there is a library I could use or if I would have to manually implement it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably manual. You'd have your `View` which you'd then have to manually manage. You could extend from TextView but that may have too much stuff you don't want.

Comment: Yeahh. I was hoping that wouldn't be the case.